# Magento 2 Shortcut/GUI tool to perform commandline tasks for windows

Tags: magento2, cli, console

I know, that the command line tool for magento 2 is very useful, but when in development,we need to perform some common tasks like clear the cache, deploy static content, upgrade db, enable extension to name a few, but for that we need to run command manually, is there any possibility to create  a GUI tool for the same?

Comment: FYI: **Magento 2 has a *developer* mode so you don't have to deploy static content all the time**.  I've wasted hours and hours in the past month redeploying static content.  So don't be like me, and switch to developer mode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using Batch program to delete it. Its to much faster than manually deletion of files.

Create a `batch` file in your magento root dir [you can place it another location too].

You can create batch file using `.bat` extension.

Right click on batch file and select `edit` [Open it into notepad] and
Type following commands into that.

```
del /s /q "E:\wamp\www\magento2\var\cache\*.*"
del /s /q "E:\wamp\www\magento2\var\page_cache\*.*"
```

Set file path as per your folder location and save the file.

Create its shortcuts on desktop for fast access.

And assign `shortcut key` to these file shortcut. Refer following screenshot.

[image]

Now whenever you will press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command from keyboard. This batch file execution will execute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use magento 2 cli in windows you can execute:

```
php bin\magento
```

So, you need:

```
php bin\magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

`bin/magento cache:flush` looks like what you need. See more in [official documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli.html)